# Spring Data Update Many To One Property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an problem with saving Many-To-One Field in Spring Data JPA.
Consider Entity User and Group as shortly described below :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Users")
    public class User {
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;

        @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @ManyToOne
        private Group group;
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "groups")
    public class Group {
       @Basic(optional = false)
       @Column(name = "name")
       private String name;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
       private Collection<User> userCollection;
    }
```

when i want to Update User Entity and change its group with CrudRepository save method following exception occured :
**org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Group was altered from 2 to 1 and** that shows spring data want to edit Group's id field while it is not corrent and **i want to change reference of it not its id**.

For Update i get view data in a DTO form and after that i convert dto object to entity object using Dozer Mapper as described below:

```
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
// get user by id from database for editing
User user = this.userService.findByIdAndDeletedFalse(form.getId());
// merge view data and entity data using Dozer
mapper.map(form, user);
// save User entity
this.userService.save(user);
```

userService is a bean that call crudRepository save method only.

Any Solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is it correct that users and groups share the same table?

Comment: Please include the update relevant code.

Comment: dear al27091 it was a mistake

Comment: Could you add the code where you update the `User.group`? The error message sounds as though you were setting a new `id` for the `Group` entity rather than changing the reference in `User`

Comment: @crizzis I change user.group.id to new selected group id and then call save method. if group is null this works well for me but if a group assigned and i want to change it i face with that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using a transient Group. You need to fetch your group and then assign the group to your user object.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you are trying to change the `id` of a tracked entity, which is not allowed in JPA. You need to obtain a reference to the new `Group` and assign it to `User.group`.

In short, instead of this:

```
user.getGroup().setId(newId);
```

Try this:

```
user.setGroup(entityManager.getReference(Group.class, newId));
```

Comment: Thanks Dear @crizizis I know that solution work but i dont want to fetch Group in contorller and i want that view data mapped and passed to save cause editing user group relationship. According to this sentences do you any suggestion ?

Comment: Well... if you don't actually load the new group, how do you even know a group with such an id (still) exists? How is JPA supposed to know?  It would have to be verified with the database anyway. I don't think there is any workaround. Note that `EntityManager.getReference` will **not** load all the fields of the `Group` entity; it will only load the id (that's the difference between `find` and `getReference`)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be loading the `Group` in the controller. You should be loading it in your service method, within the context of a transaction

Comment: In view i have a dropdown box include all groups object and passed to controller and i have group object and it's id and even other fields.

Comment: If you have a reference to the new group, just call `user.setGroup(newGroup)`

Comment: user.setGroup(newGroup) didn't work for me and exception `org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Group was altered from 6 to 1` occured again

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tell `Dozer` to exclude `group` field using the following xml.

```
<field-exclude> 
  <a>group</a> 
</field-exclude>
```

And the set the `group` manually.

```
mapper.map(form, user);
user.setGroup(this.groupService.finfById(form.group.getId()));
// save User entity
this.userService.save(user);
```

If you don't want to map the group in your controller. You could use a `DozerConverter` class where you can fetch the `group` object and set it there.

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>org.mypackage.Form</class-a>
  <class-b>org.mypackage.User</class-b>    
  <field custom-converter-id="org.mypackage.UserGroupCustomConverter">
    <a>groupId</a>
    <b>group</b>
  </field>
</mapping>  

public class UserGroupCustomConverter extends DozerConverter<Form, User> {

  public NewDozerConverter() {
    super(Form.class, User.class);
  }

  public Boolean convertTo(Form form, User user) {
     user.setGroup(this.groupService.finfById(form.group.getId()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr @alayor I dont want to fetch Group in contorller and i want that view data mapped and passed to save cause editing user group relationship. According to this sentences do you any suggestion ?